# ArcMap Find Tool Customization

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, find

I am looking to create a customized version of the find tool where the layer and field tools are pre-configured.  Ideally I could add this to ArcMap 10.1 as a button for end users to who use same search using the find button repeatedly.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to find? Do you mean search for a string with a certain field within a certain layer?

Comment: I want to search a specific field in a feature class for a string dynamically entered by the user.